# Why doesn't typescript use the 'self' trick?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote the following TypeScript code:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname:string){
}

public die(){
    this.lastname += " RIP";
}
```

And this compiles to:

```
var Person = (function() {
    function Person(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    Person.prototype.die = function () {
        this.lastname += " RIP";
    };
    return Person;
})();
```

Which of course is a valid way, but it will not work as expected in the following case:

```
function run(delegate){
    delegate();
}

var person = new Person("guy", "dude");
run(person.die);
alert(person.lastname);
alert(lastname);
```

The expected alerts here would be "dude RIP", and then "undefined". However, the actual result would be "dude" and "undefined RIP". This is because the this parameter works strangely in JS.

A common solution to that is to use a self variable by closure, and to abandon the prototype mechanism, i.e.

```
var Person = (function() {
    function Person(firstname, lastname) {
        var self = this;
        self.firstname = firstname;
        self.lastname = lastname;
        self.die = function() {
            self.lastname += " RIP";
        }
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

Which would work as expected.
What is advantage of that specific way to compile code? Did typescript decide to leave that piece of unintuitive code?

Comment: This is up to you, to the caller of the function.

Comment: Abandoning the prototype mechanism would make more unintuitive code.

Comment: Why don't you try `run(person.die.bind(person))`? How do you expect TypeScript to know that when you type `run(person.die)`, that it's meant to be compiled to `run(person.die.bind(die))` and not `run(person.die)`? Remember, [explicit is always better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: @Bergi You could abandon object-orientation altogether and opt for pure functional code.

Comment: You could also fix the `run` function to accept a context argument: `function run(delegate, context){ delegate.call(context); }`, then `run(person.die, person);`

Comment: @pawel Or even better: simply `person.die()`.

Comment: There are other solutions; I could also use: run( () => person.die());, which I find most intuitive. The problem isn't in the specific code above. The problem is that in OO code, when you pass a method, you expect it to pass with the object bound (C#, Java).

Comment: helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the structure of your code slightly to get it to use the `_this = this` pattern:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public firstName: String, public lastName: String) {
    }

    die = () => {
        this.lastName += "dead"
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
var Person = (function () {
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    var _this = this;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.die = function () {
        _this.lastName += "dead";
    };
}
return Person;
})();
```

The key part is that you need to place the die function on the object not the prototype, which forces it to use `_this = this`.

Comment: This way I can decide when I want to use this pattern, and when not to. Thanks!
I also discovered why using prototype is preferable to using this method. In this way, every object has a copy of the function, causing a larger memory footprint. Using prototypes, every object is slimmer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You should use the arrow function syntax when you want to capture this. I think it would be better to use this at the sight of delegate creation instead of class creation.

The only change needed would be:

```
run(()=>person.die());
```

This allows you to capture this for any function regardless of how it was defined.

Comment: This is WAY better than the accepted answer that is more of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is how classes in JS works. Typescript devs decided they didn't want to change any pre existing features of the lang.